# Cloud Foundry container-to-container networking via https

Tags: https, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, gorouter

We have two applications running on ibm cloud cloud foundry (appA and appB).
appA is accessing appB over a container-to-container networking while appB is also available externally over a Gorouter route.
The thing is that while it is http-8080 our app exposes - all is good.

Now we have to do container-to-container networking over https.
We configured the app to expose https-8080. 8080 is used as https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/custom-ports.html states that:

```
By default, apps only receive requests on port 8080 for both HTTP and TCP routing, 
and so must be configured, or hardcoded, to listen on this port
```

container-to-container networking works as expected now using https.
But we are no longer able to use the appB over the external Gorouter route.

What is the best way to have it all up and running as we expect?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good answer to this question, at least at the time I write this.

You do have a couple options though:

1. Manually set up HTTPS for the internal route. To do this, you would need to use the instructions for your application/server of choice to configure HTTPS. Then use whatever functionality your buildpack provides to inject this confirmation into the application container. This would also require you to bundle and push TLS certs with your application. The platform isn't going to provide you TLS certs if you take this option.

   The trick to making both the internal and public route work is that you need your application to listen on both port 8080 and the port you choose for your HTTPS traffic. As long as you continue taking HTTP traffic on port 8080, then your public routes should keep working.
2. If you want a quick, but not ideal solution you can use port 61001. For newer versions of Cloud Foundry, this port is used by Envoy to accept traffic to your app over HTTPS. Envoy then proxies the request to your app via HTTP over port 8080. You can use this port for your container to container traffic as well, however the configured subject name on the TLS cert won't match your route.

   Here's an example of what the subject name will look like.

   ```
    subject: OU=organization:639f74aa-5d97-4a47-a6b3-e9c2613729d8 + OU=space:10180e2b-33b9-44ee-9f8f-da96da17ac1a + OU=app:10a4752e-be17-41f5-bfb2-d858d49165f2; CN=b7520259-6428-4a52-60d4-5f25
   ```

   Because it's using this format, you would need to have your clients ignore certificate subject name match errors (not ideal as that weakens HTTPS), or perhaps create a custom hostname matcher.

---

For what it's worth, I don't think you want or need [to change the port](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/custom-ports.html). That is typically used if your application is not flexible and unable to listen on port 8080. It changes the port for inbound traffic. Since you're only using C2C networking, you don't need that option.

What you want, from what I understand, is that you want HTTPS for C2C traffic. In that case, the public traffic doesn't matter. It can still go through Gorouter to port 8080. For your container-to-container traffic, you can pick any port you want. You just need to make sure the port you choose has [network policy set to allow that traffic](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/cf-networking.html#create-policies) (by default all C2C traffic is blocked). Once the network policy is set, you can connect directly over whatever port you designate.